# Clarify tsconfig.json "files" list and typescript semantics

Tags: typescript

My files list:

```
    "./converter.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.core.es6.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.dom.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.es6.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.scriptHost.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/lib.webworker.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/typescript.d.ts",
    "./node_modules/typescript/bin/typescriptServices.d.ts",
    "./typings/node/node-0.10.d.ts",
    "./typings/should/should.d.ts",
    "./typings/tsd.d.ts"
```

How is this treated by the compiler and by typescript semantics? Is it as if all those files are concatenated together and then parsed as one big file?

I ask because I've seen error conditions where it looked like I had a duplicate .ts file, e.g. two versions of node....d.ts and I got what looked like a "duplicate definition" error.

If  that's the case, what's the best practice for having multiple versions of the same .ts file because I am experimenting? Or is it basically required that I prune my "installed" .d.ts files so that I have no duplicate versions?

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of your tsconfig file, I have a couple of points:

1. Your references to the `./node_modules/typescript/**` aren't necessary, tsc compiles with those by default.
2. It appears you are using `tsd`, in which case you should only need to reference `tsd.d.ts`, and your references to `./typings/node/node-0.10.d.ts` and `./typings/should/should.d.ts` are redundant.

   - The compiler follows a trail of `/// <reference />` declarations while it compiles your files.
   - `tsd.d.ts` references all the declaration files in your `typings` directory, so you don't need it.

Also, consider using [tsconfig-glob](https://github.com/wjohnsto/tsconfig-glob), as it allows you to specify a `filesGlob` and doesn't require you to manually update the `files` property in the tsconfig.

Comment: Hm, but those are automatically are generated when atom-typescript expands filesGlob. @basarat do you agree with this recommendation? Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Yes, those would be included if they are set to be included in filesGlob. Though the files may be included based on the glob, you don't need to include them. However, it shouldn't make a difference whether they are included (and referenced from tsd.d.ts) or not, as the TypeScript compiler is smart enough to only compile the same file once no matter how many time it is included.

Answer (score 1):

> Or is it basically required that I prune my "installed" .d.ts files so that I have no duplicate versions

Yes. Files that are *global* in nature (definition files are authored that way): http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html Cannot contain the same names.

Files that are modules can be duplicated at will.